# How to listen for real time changes with a mongodb datebase?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

how to listen for real time changes with a mongodb datebase in node.js? i am using mongooes with express also.

This is an example code from the mongodb Change Streams docoument
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/

```
const collection = db.collection('inventory');
const changeStream = collection.watch();
changeStream.on('change', next => {
  // process next document
});
```

where would i have to paste this code snippet to get real time update from the datebase using the code base i have below?

here is the files i have this below is the modal file

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    userId: { type: String, },
    name: { type: String, },
    movies: { type: String, },
},);
mongoose.model('users', userSchema);
```

this below is the Route file

```
const users = mongoose.model('users')

router.post('/usersCreate', async (req, res) => {

    const user = new users({ userId: 'xave12qertabnea', name: 'crsystal', movie: 'cars' });
    await user.save();
    res.send('created');
});

router.patch('/userUpdate', async (req, res) => {

    const user = await users.updateOne({ userId: 'xave12qertabnea' }, { $set: { name: 'barba', movie: 'cooking' } })
    res.send(user);
});

router.get('/usersFetch', async (req, res) => {

    const user = await users.find();
    res.send(user);
});
module.exports = router;
```

and this below is the index file

```
require('./models/users')
const usersRoute = require('./routes/usersRoute')

app.use(usersRoute);

const mongoUriii = 'mongodb+srv://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

mongoose.connect(mongoUriii, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
})

mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
    console.log('Connected to mongo instance');
});
mongoose.connection.on('error', err => {
    console.error('Error connecting to mongo', err);
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('port on')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the code in `connected` callback.

[image: Replica]

```
var watchMongodb = function () {
    const user = db.collection('users');
    const changeStream = user.watch();
    changeStream.on('change', next => {
        // process next document
    });
};

mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
    console.log('Connected to mongo instance');
    watchMongodb();
});
```

Comment: hi thank you @KingStone looking at my code what would i used to relace this line of code to work with my database `const collection = db.collection('inventory');
    const changeStream = collection.watch()` ?

Comment: what means? Do you want to watch `users` collection?

Comment: yes the users collection @KingStone why i asked is because i never used `db.collection()` to query the datebase do i need to import `db` from some where?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52247215/mongodb-watch-to-observe-change-in-database-with-nodejs-and-mongoose

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203926/discussion-between-king-stone-and-manny).