# mongoose connection to Replica Sets always fails

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, mongoose, replicaset

I am having some trouble wrapping head around how to connect to a replica set - I need to `.watch()` collection events, which requires a replica set - see: [MongoDB watch() to observe change in Database with NodeJS and Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52247215/mongodb-watch-to-observe-change-in-database-with-nodejs-and-mongoose) ( I have followed this answer as well, does not work - see bottom of this question )

Here's my setup:

- nodejs express api + mongoose
- my main 'admin' mongo db ( named `DEV` )
- 3 mongo nodes for replica setup

I have used this snippet to setup the 3 mongo nodes with docker-compose:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  mongo0:
    hostname: mongo0
    container_name: mongo0
    image: mongo:latest
    expose:
      - 30000
    ports:
      - 30000:30000
    volumes:
      - mongodb_repl_data1:/data/db
    restart: always
    command: "--bind_ip_all --replSet rs0 --port 30000"
  mongo1:
    hostname: mongo1
    container_name: mongo1
    image: mongo:latest
    expose:
      - 30001
    ports:
      - 30001:30001
    volumes:
      - mongodb_repl_data2:/data/db
    restart: always
    command: "--bind_ip_all --replSet rs0 --port 30001"
  mongo2:
    hostname: mongo2
    container_name: mongo2
    image: mongo:latest
    expose:
      - 30002
    ports:
      - 30002:30002
    volumes:
      - mongodb_repl_data3:/data/db
    restart: always
    command: "--bind_ip_all --replSet rs0 --port 30002"

volumes:
  mongodb_repl_data1:
  mongodb_repl_data2:
  mongodb_repl_data3:
```

which runs fine and I can `docker exec -it <container> mongo --port <port>` to enter the mongo shell on all of the containers.

I have my main 'admin' mongo db locally at port 27017.

I am trying to connect to them like this:

```js
await mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:30000,localhost:30001,localhost:30002,localhost:27017/DEV?replicaSet=rs0", {
   useNewUrlParser: true,
   useUnifiedTopology: true
})
```

When I run, it hangs on this `connect()`, then throwing:

```sh
Failed to inititate mongo connection:  MongooseServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongo0
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/Users/zac/Projects/score/app/application/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:821:32)
    at /Users/zac/Projects/score/app/application/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:342:10
    at /Users/zac/Projects/score/app/application/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:31:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (/Users/zac/Projects/score/app/application/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:30:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (/Users/zac/Projects/score/app/application/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:341:10)
    at Object.exports.default (/Users/zac/Projects/score/app/application/server/dist/submodules/connectDb.js:13:34)
    at start (/Users/zac/Projects/score/app/application/server/dist/index.js:31:34)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/zac/Projects/score/app/application/server/dist/index.js:47:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1075:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1096:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:940:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:781:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    setName: 'rs0',
    maxSetVersion: 1,
    maxElectionId: 7fffffff0000000000000001,
    servers: Map(3) {
      'mongo0:30000' => [ServerDescription],
      'mongo1:30001' => [ServerDescription],
      'mongo2:30002' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    compatibilityError: null,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    commonWireVersion: 9
  }
}
```

in the mongo nodes, I did do this:

```js
config={"_id":"rs0","members":[{"_id":0,"host":"mongo0:30000"},{"_id":1,"host":"mongo1:30001"},{"_id":2,"host":"mongo2:30002"}]}

rs.initiate(config);
```

which returns success:

```js
{
    "ok" : 1,
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1609794399, 1),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
        }
    },
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1609794399, 1)
}
```

and if I do `rs.status()`:

```js
rs0:SECONDARY> rs.status()
{
    "set" : "rs0",
    "date" : ISODate("2021-01-04T21:06:53.009Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "term" : NumberLong(1),
    "syncSourceHost" : "",
    "syncSourceId" : -1,
    "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
    "majorityVoteCount" : 2,
    "writeMajorityCount" : 2,
    "votingMembersCount" : 3,
    "writableVotingMembersCount" : 3,
    "optimes" : {
        "lastCommittedOpTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1609794412, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(1)
        },
        "lastCommittedWallTime" : ISODate("2021-01-04T21:06:52.570Z"),
        "readConcernMajorityOpTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1609794412, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(1)
        },
        "readConcernMajorityWallTime" : ISODate("2021-01-04T21:06:52.570Z"),
        "appliedOpTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1609794412, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(1)
        },
        "durableOpTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1609794412, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(1)
        },
        "lastAppliedWallTime" : ISODate("2021-01-04T21:06:52.570Z"),
        "lastDurableWallTime" : ISODate("2021-01-04T21:06:52.570Z")
    },
    "lastStableRecoveryTimestamp" : Timestamp(1609794411, 3),
    "electionCandidateMetrics" : {
        "lastElectionReason" : "electionTimeout",
        "lastElectionDate" : ISODate("2021-01-04T21:06:51.027Z"),
        "electionTerm" : NumberLong(1),
        "lastCommittedOpTimeAtElection" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
            "t" : NumberLong(-1)
        },
        "lastSeenOpTimeAtElection" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1609794399, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(-1)
        },
        "numVotesNeeded" : 2,
        "priorityAtElection" : 1,
        "electionTimeoutMillis" : NumberLong(10000),
        "numCatchUpOps" : NumberLong(0),
        "newTermStartDate" : ISODate("2021-01-04T21:06:51.051Z"),
        "wMajorityWriteAvailabilityDate" : ISODate("2021-01-04T21:06:52.545Z")
    },
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "mongo0:30000",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 1485,
            "optime" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1609794412, 1),
                "t" : NumberLong(1)
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2021-01-04T21:06:52Z"),
            "syncSourceHost" : "",
            "syncSourceId" : -1,
            "infoMessage" : "",
            "electionTime" : Timestamp(1609794411, 1),
            "electionDate" : ISODate("2021-01-04T21:06:51Z"),
            "configVersion" : 1,
            "configTerm" : 1,
            "self" : true,
            "lastHeartbeatMessage" : ""
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "name" : "mongo1:30001",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 2,
            "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
            "uptime" : 13,
            "optime" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1609794399, 1),
                "t" : NumberLong(-1)
            },
            "optimeDurable" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1609794399, 1),
                "t" : NumberLong(-1)
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2021-01-04T21:06:39Z"),
            "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("2021-01-04T21:06:39Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2021-01-04T21:06:51.038Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2021-01-04T21:06:52.549Z"),
            "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
            "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "",
            "syncSourceHost" : "",
            "syncSourceId" : -1,
            "infoMessage" : "",
            "configVersion" : 1,
            "configTerm" : 0
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "name" : "mongo2:30002",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 2,
            "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
            "uptime" : 13,
            "optime" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1609794399, 1),
                "t" : NumberLong(-1)
            },
            "optimeDurable" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1609794399, 1),
                "t" : NumberLong(-1)
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2021-01-04T21:06:39Z"),
            "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("2021-01-04T21:06:39Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2021-01-04T21:06:51.040Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2021-01-04T21:06:52.551Z"),
            "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
            "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "",
            "syncSourceHost" : "",
            "syncSourceId" : -1,
            "infoMessage" : "",
            "configVersion" : 1,
            "configTerm" : 0
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1,
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1609794412, 1),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
        }
    },
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1609794412, 1)
}
```

Without Docker, I have tried to use `mongodb-topology-manager` like so:
this was provided in: [MongoDB watch() to observe change in Database with NodeJS and Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52247215/mongodb-watch-to-observe-change-in-database-with-nodejs-and-mongoose)

```js
import { ReplSet } from 'mongodb-topology-manager';

export default async () => {
    // Starts a 3-node replica set on ports 31000, 31001, 31002, replica set
    // name is "rs0".
    const replSet = new ReplSet('mongod', [{ options: { port: 31000, dbpath: `${__dirname}/data/db/31000`, bind_ip: 'localhost' } },
        { options: { port: 31000, dbpath: `${__dirname}/data/db/31001`, bind_ip: 'localhost' } },
        { options: { port: 31001, dbpath: `${__dirname}/data/db/31001`, bind_ip: 'localhost' } },
        { options: { port: 31002, dbpath: `${__dirname}/data/db/31002`, bind_ip: 'localhost' } }
    ], { replSet: 'rs0' });

    try {
        console.log("rep set discovering...");
        await replSet.discover()

        console.log("rep set purging...");
        await replSet.purge();

        console.log("rep set starting...");
        await replSet.start();

        console.log("rep set done.");
    } catch (err) {
        console.error("Failed to start replica sets:", err);
    }
}
```

but if I run this, it always hangs on `replSet.start()` and never does anything, just hangs forever. The db paths exist and the ports are not used else where.

```
rep set discovering...
rep set purging...
rep set starting...
```

Simply put, how do I correctly start a mongodb repl set and connect to it via mongoose? If I need to have the repl sets locally ( not in Docker ), how do I do that with my one local mongodb instance ( so I can access them with just command `$ mongo` or `$ mongod`, not through docker )?

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: `getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongo0` looks like a name resolution error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and has been trying to find a solution for the past week. But the solution I have found is very trivial.

```
config={"_id":"rs0","members":[{"_id":0,"host":"mongo0:30000"},{"_id":1,"host":"mongo1:30001"},{"_id":2,"host":"mongo2:30002"}]}
```

I have changed the "mongo0", etc. in the host to my internal IP (ie. 192.168.1.5 and so on). It seems to have solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to automate the configuration by deploying another docker just to execute a script whose apply that configuration. So I can create a single instance un replicaset mode with this files:

- docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  mongo-setup:
    image: mongo
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - ./scripts:/scripts
    entrypoint: [ "/scripts/setup-replicaset.sh" ]
    depends_on:
      - mongodb01
  mongodb01:
    image: "mongo"
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - mongo-data:/data/db
    command: "--bind_ip_all --replSet rs0"
volumes:
 mongo-data:
    driver: local
```

- script/setup-replicaset.sh

```sh
#!/bin/bash

MONGODB1=mongodb01

echo "**********************************************" ${MONGODB1}
echo "Waiting for startup.."
until curl http://${MONGODB1}:27017/serverStatus\?text\=1 2>&1 | grep uptime | head -1; do
  echo '.'
  sleep 1
done

echo SETUP.sh time now: `date +"%T" `
mongo --host ${MONGODB1}:27017 <<EOF
var cfg = {
    "_id": "rs0",
    "protocolVersion": 1,
    "version": 1,
    "members": [
        {
            "_id": 0,
            "host": "${MONGODB1}:27017",
            "priority": 2
        }
    ],settings: {chainingAllowed: true}
};
rs.initiate(cfg, { force: true });
rs.reconfig(cfg, { force: true });
rs.slaveOk();
db.getMongo().setReadPref('nearest');
db.getMongo().setSlaveOk();
EOF
```

After run this docker-compose you can connect with mongoose normally through `localhost`.